# How can I center a div inside an absolutely positioned div?

Tags: html, css

I am using a fluid layout design and I want the div with class `center` to be centered horizontally inside of the div with class `outer`. I tried this, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"> // this div has height=0. Why?
        <div class="center">
            // stuff
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50px;
    height: auto;
}

.inner {
    width:100%;
}

.center {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Just give your `centre` div a width, like here http://jsfiddle.net/q3wx4/

Comment: Your .inner and .outer divs both have a height of 0 because "height:auto" on a div (with display:block) means "give it enough height so its static(flow) content fits inside it, if possible." If you put text inside them , then the height will be the height of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a percentage for margin-left, e.g:

```
.center
{
width:90%;
margin-left:5%;
}
```

the reason I used 5% is because since the width of center is 90% of it's container, we have 10% of space remaining, so to center it you'll have to bring it over to the left by half of the available space; which in this case is 5%

Comment: I use @TrevorRudolph's approach a lot, and your approach some times, unless I have to add max-width or min-width to `.center`

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much for your help. This is a clever technique.

Answer (score 0):

You've gotta treat the inner as if it's a regular `div` in a page, so something like:

```
#inner {
    position:fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width:234px;
    height:90px;
    margin-top:-45px; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
    margin-left:-117px; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your width*/
    border: 0.5px solid #ccc;
}
```

This would do the trick and you can adjust accordingly .

Comment: The problem is that this is a fluid layout, and the width of the div with class ``center`` changes.

Comment: what webengine do you use?

Comment: What do you mean by 'webengine'? Web browser? I test on everything except IE.

Comment: why are you confused that the height=0, div have no default proportion so since it was not set it stays as 0

Comment: How can it be height=0 when it contains divs that have height > 0? Intuitively, this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Inline-block is probably the best option for the centered div, then use our outer div with text-align:center to center the inner container. You don't really need an inner and a center div the way you have it, but I kept it in for examples sake. Below is a fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/UYw8S/2/

Borders and padding added for example.

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="center">
           Inner stuff
       </div>
   </div>
</div>

.outer {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 50px;
height: auto;
background:#ccc;
border:1px solid #333;
}

.inner {
display:block;
margin:10px;
border:1px solid #333;
text-align:center;
}

.center {
margin:10px 0;
text-align:left;
height:40px;
width:80%;
display:inline-block;
background:#fff;
padding:10px;
}
```